# Convert Time from one time zone to another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

My `created_at` timestamps are stored in UTC:

```
>> Annotation.last.created_at
=> Sat, 29 Aug 2009 23:30:09 UTC +00:00
```

How do I convert one of them to 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' (taking into account daylight savings)? Something like:

```
Annotation.last.created_at.in_eastern_time
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Use the in_time_zone method of the DateTime class

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.2)
>> now = DateTime.now.utc
=> Sun, 06 Sep 2009 22:27:45 +0000
>> now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Sun, 06 Sep 2009 18:27:45 EDT -04:00
>> quit
```

So for your particular example

```
Annotation.last.created_at.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

Comment: or you can just use hour ident `now.in_time_zone(3)`

Comment: `created_at.in_time_zone("EST")` is shorter

Comment: "EST" = "Eastern Standard Time", so it will be wrong during Daylight Saving Time. "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" figures out whether it's DST or not for you.

Comment: Note that the in_time_zone method is part of ActiveSupport, thus it is built into Rails, but is not part of the Ruby stdlib.  If you have a rails app, no problem.  If you have a straight Ruby app you'll need to be sure to require active support.

Comment: Link to the documentation for this method is here: https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone

Answer (score 19):

Although this is an old question, it's worth mentioning something. In a [previous reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386895/164989) it's suggested to use a before_filter to set the timezone temporally.

You should **never, ever** do that because Time.zone stores the information in the thread, and it will probably leak to the next request handled by that thread.

Instead you should use an around_filter to make sure that the Time.zone is reset after the request is complete. Something like:

```
around_filter :set_time_zone

private

def set_time_zone
  old_time_zone = Time.zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if logged_in?
  yield
ensure
  Time.zone = old_time_zone
end
```

Read more about this [here](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2011/02/03/how-to-set-a-time-zone-for-each-request-in-rails/)

Comment: There is a nice [Time.use_zone](https://apidock.com/rails/Time/use_zone/class) method nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

If you add this to your `/config/application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Then you can cell

```
Annotation.last.created_at.in_time_zone
```

to get the time in the specified time zone.

Comment: if we are configuring time zone in application.rb then no need to call ".in_time_zone". rails automatically do it for us jyst need to call Annotation.last.created_at

Answer (score 4):

If you configure your `/config/application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

Time.now.in_time_zone

DateTime.now.in_time_zone
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your timezone to Eastern Time.

You can set your default timezone in config/environment.rb

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

Now all records you pull out will be in that time zone. If you need different time zones, say  based on a user timezone you can change it with a before_filter in your controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_timezone

  def set_timezone
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
  end
end
```

Just make sure you are storing all your times in the database as UTC and everything will be sweet.

Comment: Does this matter if you are running an application server like mongrel, thin or passenger? They run more than one instance, single threaded I believe? I may be wrong, would love to know!

Comment: `Time.zone=` is thread-safe https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb#L36-38.

Comment: It may not have been in '09 ?

Comment: It is absolutely a problem running on Heroku... setting Time.zone = for one user WILL change the time.zone for another user

Comment: @jpwynn: according to this: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c911e1ac08d119e94fcec6973a012f4cd198ecee it's Thread safe since more than 5 years. Any source or example for your Problem?

Comment: I did not say Time.zone was not thread safe. I said it would bleed from one user's session (if set) into another user's session.

Comment: A thread can serve multiple sessions. It you set it once when user is logged in, for example, the LAST user to log in will set the timezone for ALL users whose session uses that same thread. So you MUST use a before_filter to set it for every user for every page load.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to parse a datetime string into a timezone, then convert it to another timezone

```rb
datetime = "2021-01-14 05:30"

datetime_in_ET = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].parse(datetime)
#=> Thu, 14 Jan 2021 05:30:00 EST -05:00

datetime_in_ET.in_time_zone("Australia/Melbourne")
# => Thu, 14 Jan 2021 21:30:00 AEDT +11:00
```

For reference: [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#Constants) are the available timezone strings:

```rb
{ "International Date Line West" => "Etc/GMT+12", "Midway Island" => "Pacific/Midway", "American Samoa" => "Pacific/Pago_Pago", "Hawaii" => "Pacific/Honolulu", "Alaska" => "America/Juneau", "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" => "America/Los_Angeles", "Tijuana" => "America/Tijuana", "Mountain Time (US & Canada)" => "America/Denver", "Arizona" => "America/Phoenix", "Chihuahua" => "America/Chihuahua", "Mazatlan" => "America/Mazatlan", "Central Time (US & Canada)" => "America/Chicago", "Saskatchewan" => "America/Regina", "Guadalajara" => "America/Mexico_City", "Mexico City" => "America/Mexico_City", "Monterrey" => "America/Monterrey", "Central America" => "America/Guatemala", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" => "America/New_York", "Indiana (East)" => "America/Indiana/Indianapolis", "Bogota" => "America/Bogota", "Lima" => "America/Lima", "Quito" => "America/Lima", "Atlantic Time (Canada)" => "America/Halifax", "Caracas" => "America/Caracas", "La Paz" => "America/La_Paz", "Santiago" => "America/Santiago", "Newfoundland" => "America/St_Johns", "Brasilia" => "America/Sao_Paulo", "Buenos Aires" => "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires", "Montevideo" => "America/Montevideo", "Georgetown" => "America/Guyana", "Puerto Rico" => "America/Puerto_Rico", "Greenland" => "America/Godthab", "Mid-Atlantic" => "Atlantic/South_Georgia", "Azores" => "Atlantic/Azores", "Cape Verde Is." => "Atlantic/Cape_Verde", "Dublin" => "Europe/Dublin", "Edinburgh" => "Europe/London", "Lisbon" => "Europe/Lisbon", "London" => "Europe/London", "Casablanca" => "Africa/Casablanca", "Monrovia" => "Africa/Monrovia", "UTC" => "Etc/UTC", "Belgrade" => "Europe/Belgrade", "Bratislava" => "Europe/Bratislava", "Budapest" => "Europe/Budapest", "Ljubljana" => "Europe/Ljubljana", "Prague" => "Europe/Prague", "Sarajevo" => "Europe/Sarajevo", "Skopje" => "Europe/Skopje", "Warsaw" => "Europe/Warsaw", "Zagreb" => "Europe/Zagreb", "Brussels" => "Europe/Brussels", "Copenhagen" => "Europe/Copenhagen", "Madrid" => "Europe/Madrid", "Paris" => "Europe/Paris", "Amsterdam" => "Europe/Amsterdam", "Berlin" => "Europe/Berlin", "Bern" => "Europe/Zurich", "Zurich" => "Europe/Zurich", "Rome" => "Europe/Rome", "Stockholm" => "Europe/Stockholm", "Vienna" => "Europe/Vienna", "West Central Africa" => "Africa/Algiers", "Bucharest" => "Europe/Bucharest", "Cairo" => "Africa/Cairo", "Helsinki" => "Europe/Helsinki", "Kyiv" => "Europe/Kiev", "Riga" => "Europe/Riga", "Sofia" => "Europe/Sofia", "Tallinn" => "Europe/Tallinn", "Vilnius" => "Europe/Vilnius", "Athens" => "Europe/Athens", "Istanbul" => "Europe/Istanbul", "Minsk" => "Europe/Minsk", "Jerusalem" => "Asia/Jerusalem", "Harare" => "Africa/Harare", "Pretoria" => "Africa/Johannesburg", "Kaliningrad" => "Europe/Kaliningrad", "Moscow" => "Europe/Moscow", "St. Petersburg" => "Europe/Moscow", "Volgograd" => "Europe/Volgograd", "Samara" => "Europe/Samara", "Kuwait" => "Asia/Kuwait", "Riyadh" => "Asia/Riyadh", "Nairobi" => "Africa/Nairobi", "Baghdad" => "Asia/Baghdad", "Tehran" => "Asia/Tehran", "Abu Dhabi" => "Asia/Muscat", "Muscat" => "Asia/Muscat", "Baku" => "Asia/Baku", "Tbilisi" => "Asia/Tbilisi", "Yerevan" => "Asia/Yerevan", "Kabul" => "Asia/Kabul", "Ekaterinburg" => "Asia/Yekaterinburg", "Islamabad" => "Asia/Karachi", "Karachi" => "Asia/Karachi", "Tashkent" => "Asia/Tashkent", "Chennai" => "Asia/Kolkata", "Kolkata" => "Asia/Kolkata", "Mumbai" => "Asia/Kolkata", "New Delhi" => "Asia/Kolkata", "Kathmandu" => "Asia/Kathmandu", "Astana" => "Asia/Dhaka", "Dhaka" => "Asia/Dhaka", "Sri Jayawardenepura" => "Asia/Colombo", "Almaty" => "Asia/Almaty", "Novosibirsk" => "Asia/Novosibirsk", "Rangoon" => "Asia/Rangoon", "Bangkok" => "Asia/Bangkok", "Hanoi" => "Asia/Bangkok", "Jakarta" => "Asia/Jakarta", "Krasnoyarsk" => "Asia/Krasnoyarsk", "Beijing" => "Asia/Shanghai", "Chongqing" => "Asia/Chongqing", "Hong Kong" => "Asia/Hong_Kong", "Urumqi" => "Asia/Urumqi", "Kuala Lumpur" => "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur", "Singapore" => "Asia/Singapore", "Taipei" => "Asia/Taipei", "Perth" => "Australia/Perth", "Irkutsk" => "Asia/Irkutsk", "Ulaanbaatar" => "Asia/Ulaanbaatar", "Seoul" => "Asia/Seoul", "Osaka" => "Asia/Tokyo", "Sapporo" => "Asia/Tokyo", "Tokyo" => "Asia/Tokyo", "Yakutsk" => "Asia/Yakutsk", "Darwin" => "Australia/Darwin", "Adelaide" => "Australia/Adelaide", "Canberra" => "Australia/Melbourne", "Melbourne" => "Australia/Melbourne", "Sydney" => "Australia/Sydney", "Brisbane" => "Australia/Brisbane", "Hobart" => "Australia/Hobart", "Vladivostok" => "Asia/Vladivostok", "Guam" => "Pacific/Guam", "Port Moresby" => "Pacific/Port_Moresby", "Magadan" => "Asia/Magadan", "Srednekolymsk" => "Asia/Srednekolymsk", "Solomon Is." => "Pacific/Guadalcanal", "New Caledonia" => "Pacific/Noumea", "Fiji" => "Pacific/Fiji", "Kamchatka" => "Asia/Kamchatka", "Marshall Is." => "Pacific/Majuro", "Auckland" => "Pacific/Auckland", "Wellington" => "Pacific/Auckland", "Nuku'alofa" => "Pacific/Tongatapu", "Tokelau Is." => "Pacific/Fakaofo", "Chatham Is." => "Pacific/Chatham", "Samoa" => "Pacific/Apia" }
```