# How to work with Timezone information

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Time from one time zone to another in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386871/convert-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-rails)

I have a form that gathers date, a time, and the timezone of the user.

I have set up my application to be using Bangkok timezone as that is the timezone I am working.

When I get the time and timezone from the user I want to convert the time data to the Bangkok Time using the timezone information from the user.

How to I do the calculation using the timezone of the user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386871/convert-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-rails