# Manage timezone properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have a backend written in RoR, and I need to manage many requests from different peers around the world. I have the following questions:

- Is it proper to change the `config.timezone` for each request ?

  - If **yes**:

    - Assuming that 2 requests arrive on my server at the same time. Will the timezone be different for both ? (Means, will there be two differents `config.timezone` ?)
    - I don't find any way to set the config timezone with desired UTC, like `Time.zone = 'UTC+X'`
  - If **no**:

    - Do you know any way to manage it easily and properly ? I have a lot of timezone operations to do, then it would be easier to set it in configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the answers to this question:
[Convert Time from one time zone to another in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386871/convert-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-rails)

It seems like using config.timezone is a bad idea due to threading issues.

I would recommend using the ActiveSupport TimeZone and TimeWithZone classes.
This allows you to do things along the lines of:

```
# Return the simultaneous time in Time.zone or the specified zone
Time.now.in_time_zone                      # => Tue, 13 Jul 2010 01:20:55 EDT -04:00
Time.now.in_time_zone(Time.zone)           # => Tue, 13 Jul 2010 01:20:55 EDT -04:00
Time.now.in_time_zone("Asia/Vladivostok")  # => Tue, 13 Jul 2010 16:20:55 VLAST +11:00
Time.now.in_time_zone(-3.hours)            # => Tue, 13 Jul 2010 02:20:55 BRT -03:00

# Switch to a given timezone within a block
Time.use_zone "Asia/Vladivostok" do
  Time.zone.now # => Tue, 13 Jul 2010 16:20:55 VLAST +11:00
end
```

Sample code is from http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596521424/active-support.html

Take a look under 'Time Zone Conversions'

Comment: I don't find how to change Time.zone with UTC offset, like `Time.zone="UTC+X"`

Comment: Finally found it : `Time.zone = X`. Simply.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to change `config.timezone` for each request, but yes, timezone should be handled on per request basis.

Check out the excellent & comprehensive blogpost titled Working with time zones in [Ruby on Rails](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails) by the folks at [elabs](http://www.elabs.se) for advice on how to deal with multiple timezones.

Ryan Bates' revised version of [Time Zones RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised) is another good resource.