# Ruby/Rails: Convert from one timezone to another (not necessarily UTC)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I know there a lot of questions along the lines of "how to convert from local to utc", but i think i want something slightly different. Apologies if i am repeating another question (i did search).

I want to convert from one DateTime with Timezone to another DateTime with Timezone, ie:

`07/31/2013 18:14:46.676 America/New_York -> 08/01/2013 23:14:46.676 Europe/London`

I have looked at [TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) but it seems to assume you set a local timezone and then convert to/from UTC which is not what i want.

Thanks

Comment: Ruby have a method in_time_zone and you can view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386871/convert-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-rails

Comment: First convert to from `America/New_York` to UTC.  Then convert from UTC to `Europe/London`.  On the first leg, be prepared to deal with ambiguous input due to DST.