# Converting datetime with one timezone to utc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails4 app, I have date given in two strings, one gives timestamp, while other gives which timezone this is in:

```
a = "04/23/2014 04:00"
b = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

I want to convert this date to utc, so that I can save it in UTC

```
"2014-04-23 08:00:00 UTC"
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Use `.utc` to get the time in UTC format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) method on the Rails `DateTime` class, you can parse a `DateTime` object from a string containing **both** the time and timezone (timezone is passed via the `%z` directive). From there, you can convert the time to UTC:

```
a = "04/23/2014 04:00"
b = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"

datetime_with_tz = DateTime.strptime([a, b].join(' '), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %z")
#=> Wed, 23 Apr 2014 04:00:00 -0500

datetime_with_tz.utc
#=> Wed, 23 Apr 2014 09:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: datetime = DateTime.parse(a)  gives
ArgumentError: invalid date

Comment: @JVK, yeah, that's a small hitch with the way the date string is formatted. Try using [`strptime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class) in order to specify a format. I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: @JKV, have a look at my updated answer. It cuts down on steps by parsing a DateTime object from a time string – _including a __timezone___ – which enables the correct UTC time to be parsed from the datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Use the in_time_zone method of the DateTime class

Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.2)

```
>> now = DateTime.now.utc
=> Sun, 06 Sep 2009 22:27:45 +0000
>> now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Sun, 06 Sep 2009 18:27:45 EDT -04:00
>> quit
```

So for your particular example

```
a.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

Comment: You've simply copied this answer [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386871/convert-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-rails). That's why it says _Rails 2.3.2_. The OP is asking for a solution in Rails 4.

Comment: But that operations also can works in rails4, I didn't try but i thing it must work.

Comment: a.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') gives 
ArgumentError: argument out of range