# Check user attributes according to his timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, timezone

Attributes are `start_time`,`end_time`,`time_zone`

I save user `time_zone` by using `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.names` dropdown.
e.g

```
start_time => "09:00"
end_time => "02:00"
time_zone => "Samoa"
```

Now I can't understand how I check user start_time and end_time according to his timezone.I can't move further due to non understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Time from one time zone to another in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386871/convert-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the `start_time` and `end_time` in UTC or relative to the local time zone? To compare UTC to local time, you would use the #in_time_zone method.

```
Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'        # => 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
Time.utc(2007, 2, 10, 20, 30, 45).in_time_zone  # => Sat, 10 Feb 2007 15:30:45 EST -05:00
```

Comment: Is this I do when save or when retrieve?