# Parse DateTime with a specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I get some time input from a user (living in Toronto), which is the time someone wants to start their schedule, i.e.,

```
start = "4:00 PM"
```

I have to convert it into a `DateTime`. When I save it, I want to get:

```
16:00 #{local_time_zone}
```

but if save it, it will save it as:

```
16:00 UTC
```

So, I decided to use `DateTime.parse`. I expect to get:

```
2018-05-14 16:00:00 -0400
```

but I get from my code:

```
unit_time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Time.parse("#{start} #{unit_time_zone}")
# => 2018-05-14 16:00:00 +0000
```

I even tried to parse `Time`, convert it into seconds, and parse that into a `DateTime`. It does not account for the user's time.

How can I get a string of time in the format `"3:00 PM"` in a specific timezone, and not convert 3:00 PM in Toronto, 3:00 PM in Tokyo, etc.?

Comment: How do you know which time zone the user is in? Or is that part of your question - are you asking how it should be collected/stored?

Comment: @TomLord I know what timezone User's are in. I want to get the put whatever the `time` string is (ie. "3:00 PM") and just merge their timezone with that time. It's hard to explain.

Comment: @dsomel21 try this : `start.to_time.in_time_zone(unit_time_zone)` (solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386889/9541423))

Comment: @sovalina That's not what I want at all. This is converting timezones. I want to be able to say "3:00" UTC and then be able to change it to "3 PM" New York without change the hour.

Comment: @dsomel21ok i get it, so how about : `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(unit_time_zone).strptime(start, '%I:%M %p')`